# How to tune the prediction (svc.predict()) of Support Vector Classifier (SVC) by adjusting the threshold of decision function?

Tags: scikit-learn

I read in a forum that decision_function returns the distance between the data_point (e.g, (x1,y1) ) and the decision boundary. So my assumption is that if adjustments could be made on this decision boundary output could also be fine-tuned.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question

Comment: Why do you want to adjust the decision boundary, which was learned from the data? May be you want to do [CalibratedClassifierCV](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV.html#sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV) ?